# Failed to start Emulator console for 5554

Tags: android, emulation, ddms

I'm trying execute my application, but it occurs the following problem:

Failed to start Emulator console for 5554

I've already done:

Clean and Build Project and restart

Comment: Any additional info about the error?

Comment: Try increasing the adb timeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check:**

- if you have downloaded all of the emulator files from the SDK Manager for the version you're trying to use.
- if you have enough RAM left to use for the emulator (remember that you define it in the device config)
- if there's not another emulator already running.

Another way to know what's the problem is to check the LogCat, it provides very useful information about errors and all the stuff running, if you can't figure the problem reading it, try to ask a question with the error message FROM the LogCat, not only the one from the windows in your screen.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Finally I launched the emulator in command line. use "`sudo ./emulator @(your device name)`", and it can work properly with port 5554.